# VBA - on click - generate a prompt to confirm which workbook / spreadsheet to look at

Tags: excel, vba, onclick, copy, prompt

I am fairly certain I know how to select data from a different workbook / sheet but I'm a little clueless as to how I would go about generating a VBA question box that would prompt the user on click to input the relevant workbook / sheet.

For example:

Workbook 1, sheet 1 needs data

Workbook 2, sheet 2 has data

Workbook 1 would contain a button called 'get data'.

On click - 'Get Data' button would prompt the user to input the workbook and subsequently the worksheet to copy from.

Once the user specifies workbook 2, sheet 2, the range to copy from the selected sheet/book would always be the same (regardless of the sheet ref) so the data would be collected from workbook 2, sheet 2 and would then be pasted back into workbook 1, sheet 1.

- Workbook 1, sheet 1 will always be used to paste data into.

I hope I haven't explained this in too confusing a manner, I've been going over this in my head for a while, so if anyone needs clarity, then please shout!

Many thanks.

Comment: You want a lot more than a `Msgbox`. So a `UserForm` but that's got a lot of code behind it and no-one here is going to waste the minutes required. If you're serious about using this site then see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way would be to **create a UserForm**

with 2*2 comboboxes (1 for workbooks (here Cb_Wb) and one for sheets (here Cb_Ws), 2 times : source and destination)

With that code :

```
Private Sub Cb_Wb_Change()
Me.Cb_Ws.Clear
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In Workbooks(Me.Cb_Wb.Value).Worksheets
    Me.Cb_Ws.AddItem ws.Name
Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    Me.Cb_Wb.AddItem wb.Name
Next wb

End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic. - Just what I was after! - Cheers. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Enjoy! ;)

Comment: Many Thanks again, I've got the userform in place and am now having problems with the window selection! :S - I've created a sub for a button click within the userform in order to process the selection. E.g. Workbook1, Worksheet 1 is the selection, so now I want to be able to upon the button click, select the relevant sheet? - I've tried setting the Cb_Wb value as a workbook and I've had no luck! - Any further help is appreciated!

Comment: In your code, you should refer to them like this : `Workbooks(Me.Cb_Wb.Value).Worksheets(Me.Cb_Ws.Value)` if the code is in the UserForm. If not, just change `Me.` to `UserFormName.`

Comment: Much obliged. - I did ask this as a separate question and have somehow muddled through. With this I've experimented with some other areas and have learned a lot, so I reiterate my thanks! :)